# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/json/JSONObject eventhough jar present WEB-INF/lib directory

Tags: java, json, jsp, servlets

> 00000ab ServletWrappe E com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper
>   service SRVE0014E: Uncaught service() exception root cause
>   /api/getDataWAX.jsp:
>   com.ibm.websphere.servlet.error.ServletErrorReport:
>   java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/json/JSONObject.

I am using java-json.jar to convert an JSON to XML. It works fine in all environment but in Production it gives java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError.
I don't have access to Production environment. The jar is present in .ear file in xyz.ear/xyz.war/WEB-INF/lib/java-json.jar

Answer (score 0):

A `java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError` is not the same as a `java.lang.ClassNotFoundException`. In some cases, it is possible that the class loader locates the file but couldn't instantiate the class, for example, a missing class in a hierarchy or a fail during static initialization.

So, although you have `java-json.jar` in your production environment, maybe you are missing some dependencies for this package.